# update value in first row of partition. sqlanywhere17

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

given a Table T

| id | FKey | col_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | NULL |
| 3 | 2 | NULL |
| 4 | 3 | NULL |
| 5 | 4 | NULL |
| 6 | 4 | NULL |
| 7 | 4 | NULL |
| 8 | 5 | NULL |
| 9 | 5 | NULL |

i want to Update each row with the highest id with value 1 for each given ForeignKey
So my result looks like this:

| id | FKey | col_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | NULL |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | 4 | NULL |
| 7 | 4 | NULL |
| 8 | 5 | 1 |
| 9 | 5 | NULL |

please keep in mind that i am using sqlanywhere 17 so while

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT id, fkey, col_value, 
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY fkey ORDER BY ID ASC) AS rn
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
```

shows me the resultrows i need,
i can not update them with

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT id, fkey, col_value, 
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY fkey ORDER BY ID ASC) AS rn
)
UPDATE cte SET value = 1
```

As is possible with other SQL systems and marked as a solution in countless other threads.

I just get syntaxerror at "UPDATE"

i am also unable join cte to table t and update that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core ANSI SQL solution, expected to execute on any dbms:

```
UPDATE T t1
SET Value = 1
WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM T t2 WHERE t1.fkey = t2.fkey)
```

Note that `VALUE` is a SQL reserved word (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words), might need to be delimited as `"Value"`, or perhaps `[Value]`.

Comment: thanks that works :) i was super stuck!
i have updated the question from "Value" to "col_value" to avoid confusion since the table is simplefied and the names are arbitrary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it does. i just tried it. i just put an AS in there before the alias as i find that more readable.

Comment: @C0nan . . . I don't like `as` in that context, but glad to know it works.